# C# .Net Wrapper for COM Dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, design-patterns, com-interop

Our new applications 
1) web application (MVC3) 
2) Webservices 
needs to communicate via interops with our COM based Business Layer

We are planning to  create a wrapper for the business layer in .Net to  Decouple the COM dlls from the above 2 so that we have one place(wrapper) to make any enhancements or totally replace COM to something else.

```
          For eg: if there is a COMClassA and ICOMClassA. create a new WrapperClassA in .Net which will essentially have an instance of the COMClassA and required properties.
```

Use WrapperClassA in web application and webservices

My question 
          1) Is this the right approach ?
    2) If so What is the best approach to create the .Net Wrapper.
There are around 100+ Classes and corresponding interfaces for the COM dlls. Any code generation techniques ?
    3) Can we use some design patterns to minimize code generation
    or Is there any other alternate to decouple the COM Based Business Layer

Please note: We don't want to create Web services and consume in ASP .Net Application since we believe there could  be considerable performance issues.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. 
Stackoverflow community you are doing a great job.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

David Wheeler -

> Any problem in computer science can be solved with another layer of indirection.

I agree with the following statement in your question:

> We are planning to create a wrapper for the business layer in .Net to Decouple the COM dlls from the above 2 so that we have one place(wrapper) to make any enhancements or totally replace COM to something else.

This allows you to "pick and choose" your problem areas, rewrite areas, or leave alone areas.  I can almost guarantee that at least one of your COM components executes some black magic... written by some ex-consultant or ex-employee five years ago... LOL

Unfortunately as far as I know you will have to manually code/design your layer (or layers) of indirection.  However, some of the VS.NET (and Resharper and CodeRush) refactor/auto-generate methods will help you out a little.  But at the end of the day **you** know your product (and design) better than anyone (or any tool).